# Embedding of regular spaces in countably compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

It is well-known that each completely regular space embeds into a compact Hausdorff space.

> **Problem.** Is it true that each regular space embeds into a countably compact Hausdorff space?

---

The problem was posed on 31.08.2019 by Serhii Bardyla (sbardyla@yahoo.com) on page [161](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=2&page=161) of [Volume 2](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=2) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=2).

**Prize:** Beer + pizza in ``Cosa Nostra''.